# Is it possible to define a multiperiod optimization with Pyomo network?

Tags: pyomo

I'm looking for help in solving an optimization problem using Pyomo with multi-period optimization. Specifically, I have declared a block with certain variables for a set of time periods (m.date), and I am trying to declare an extensive port (because I plan to split the stream later in the problem). However, I'm facing an issue in correctly defining the port. Here is the relevant code:

First, I initialize the set of time periods (m.date), which contains 120 periods:

```
    m.date = Set(initialize=output.index, ordered=True)  # Initialize the set of time periods
```

Next, I have a block of three variables defined as follows:

```
    def block_fx_CSP(m, t):     
        m.area_fxCSP = Var(within=NonNegativeReals, doc='# area fixed CSP')     
        m.fxCSP = Var(within=NonNegativeReals, doc='Canadian Solar fixed PV (W)')     
        m.y_fxCSP = Var(domain=Binary) 
    m.fxCSP_block = Block(m.date, rule=block_fx_CSP)
```

I've tried a few different approaches for the port declaration, but none of them provide the correct output.

My goal is to have a port that corresponds to each time period. Here are my attempts and the issues with each:

1st Attempt:

I declared the port like this, but it gives me a list of the same first period date variable for all time periods:

```
    for t in m.date:     
        m.port_fxCSP = Port(m.date, initialize=[(m.fxCSP_block[t].fxCSP, Port.Extensive)])
```

```
    #The output is not correct:
    Key: Name  : Size : Variable
    2019-12-31 19:00:00 : fxCSP :1 : fxCSP_block[2019-12-31 19:00:00].fxCSP
    2019-12-31 20:00:00 : fxCSP :1 : fxCSP_block[2019-12-31 19:00:00].fxCSP
    2019-12-31 21:00:00 : fxCSP :1 : fxCSP_block[2019-12-31 19:00:00].fxCSP
    2019-12-31 22:00:00 : fxCSP :1 : fxCSP_block[2019-12-31 19:00:00].fxCS
```

```
    #The output should be:
    2019-12-31 19:00:00 : fxCSP : 1 : fxCSP_block[2019-12-31 19:00:00].fxCSP
    2019-12-31 20:00:00 : fxCSP : 1 : fxCSP_block[2019-12-31 20:00:00].fxCSP
    2019-12-31 21:00:00 : fxCSP : 1 : fxCSP_block[2019-12-31 21:00:00].fxCSP
    2019-12-31 22:00:00 : fxCSP : 1 : fxCSP_block[2019-12-31 22:00:00].fxCSP
```

2nd Attempt:

I declared the port and added variables to it iteratively, but it replaces all the data, resulting in a port with a single output:

```
    m.port_fxCSP = Port() 
    for t in m.date:     
        m.port_fxCSP.add(m.fxCSP_block[t].fxCSP, Port.Extensive)
```

Output:
port_fxCSP : Size=1, Index=None
Key : Name : Size : Variable
None : <function Port.Extensive at 0x00000165C26A65F0> : 1 : fxCSP_block[2020-01-05 18:00:00].fxCSP

3rd Attempt:

I tried to declare a function for the port for each m.date as an iterable, but I encountered an error indicating that the function is not iterable:

```
    def port_fxCSP(m, t):     
        return [(m.fxCSP_block[t].fxCSP, Port.Extensive) for t in m.date] 
    m.fxCSP_port = Port(m.date, initialize=port_fxCSP)
```

However, I received a TypeError, stating that the 'function' object is not iterable.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or guidance on how to correctly define the port so that it corresponds to each time period as intended. Thank you!